While working with poi-ooxml-5.2.5.jar , getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream
Error while exporting xls file using poi-ooxml-5.2.5.jar
Getting below error :
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream
Validated all the dependencies.
Tried ClassLoader in java class and created instance of org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream
It is successfully creating.

Complete stack-trace please!

poi-ooxml depends on commons-compress. You can see the dependencies at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/5.2.5 - which takes the pom file that we publish and provides a web view of it. You should consider using a build tool like maven or gradle - these will import dependencies for you.
